# Strange behavior of ADD in asm

Tags: c, gcc, x86, inline-assembly

The output of this code:

```
int i=0;
while(i<5)
    {
    asm volatile
        (
        "addl $1,%0"
        :"=r"(i)
        :
        :"memory"
        );
    printf("%d\n",i);
    }
```

is like this:

```
2
3
3
3
.
.
.
```

But it should be like this:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

Why is that so? I can't seem to understand where the problem is.

Comment: examine the disassembly.  although compilers can/will vary, it didnt initialize the register, but did increment it each time through the loop.  When you use jlahd's answer you will see it adds an instruction to zero the register before the loop.

Answer (score 1):

You are specifying `i` as an output-only operand. That is, the compiler uses the output of the register `%0` for the variable, but the current value if `i` is *not* copied to the register at the beginning.

Specify `i` as input as well, for the same register:

```
asm volatile
    (
    "addl $1,%0"
    :"=r"(i)
    :"0"(i)
    :"memory"
    );
```

Comment: Thanks but is it a typo at line 5 of your code? Shouldn't it be :"r"(i)?

Comment: or much more simply, `"+r"(i)` to declare a read-write operand.  You normally only use a separate matching constraint for a separate variable, i.e. when the semantic meaning matches that syntax.

Comment: Wait, ADD doesn't take any register operand in this code. It's a memory operand. What register are you talking about? If there's any register involved, shouldn't it be clobbered?

Comment: @Tuhnri: No, you only declare clobbers on things you modify that *aren't* outputs. (Incidentally, this asm statement should not be declared `volatile`, and should not have a `"memory"` clobber. It's fine to let the compiler optimize it away if the value of `i` isn't needed.) And BTW, no `:"r"(i)` as an input would let the compile pick a different register than the destination, so you'd have to write it as `lea 1(%1), %0` to use both operands.  `"0"` is a matching constraint: whatever register `%0` picked. https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Simple-Constraints.html#index-constraint_002c-matching

Comment: @Tuhnri: also, WTF are you talking about with a memory operand?  `r` means register.  Have you still not looked at the compiler's asm output from the inline asm you're trying to write in your recent questions?

Comment: @Peter Cordes: But everything we modify is considered output, right? Would you please give an example of a modified variable that isn't output?

Comment: i is an Lvalue in that template so it's only written to, not read. I didn't use any read instructions. Why should it be declared as input?

Comment: What do you think the add instruction does? What two values does it add?